# SQL Update sot issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the cost of an item in our database:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.PartMaster
SET Cost = ‭0.0017178141193889‬
WHERE PartNumber = '93275K12'
```

I am getting an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '‭'.

The `Cost` is of `float` type. I have updated costs before without issue. But cannot find what the syntax issue is. Please help

Comment: try to put `;` in the end of the update statement.

Comment: I am able to execute without issues.

Comment: I tried putting ; at the end and the I now get Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: is this the exact query you used (copy and paste from the query window) ?

Comment: there seems to be some unprintable character before and after your floating piont number. delete line 2 and re-type in manually and try. See `select SUBSTRING('Cost = ‭0.0017178141193889‬', 8, 1)` the string is copied from your post

Comment: Yes, this is the exact query from the query window. Are you saying to delete line 2 and add it to the select statement. I am unclear about the select substring command

Comment: delete the second line and re-key in manually. Don't copy and paste from your source

Comment: OK, I manually entered SET Cost = 0.0017178141193889 and still see the same error. I even tried setting Cost = 0 and get the same results

Comment: did you delete the entire line and re-key ? Or you just replaced the text ? I copied your query into Notepad2 and it show 2 unprintable character before and after the floating point number

Comment: Ok, I re-typed the entire code block and it is working. Thank for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

copy/paste into something like NotePad++ and make sure all hidden characters are visible. I've seen this a lot when copying/pasting values from emails, there are hidden characters that SSMS can't show. 
or if that doesn't show anything, open in a new tab and re-type it all without copy/pasting. (only 3 lines so not a big job)

Comment: I tried this and there are no hidden characters